# Criando uma área de inserção de anúncios WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Dentro do WordPress eu queria criar um campo, que quando eu postagem uma imagem em destaque ele deixaria a imagem lá, coisa simples (acho).
Exemplo é o Orbit Slider, onde as imagens em destaque viram sliders.
Alguém sabe um caminho simples para fazer isso ou alguma documentação que me indique o caminho?

Vamos dizer que quero separar 4 tipo de box e quando a pessoas criar uma postagem com uma imagem linkada aparecesse nesse espaço.

Ex: Vou em "Criar Anuncio", Escolho "Box Lateral 01" e anexo uma imagem de acordo com o tamanha do box e digito o link e pronto aparece lá.

Comment: Existem várias maneiras de fazer isso. Você tinha que especificar melhor seu objetivo. É galeria de imagens? É só uma imagem? É global ou específico para cada post/página?

Comment: Olá amigo... vamos dizer que quero separar 4 tipo de box... e quando a pessoas criar uma postagem com uma imagem linkada... aparecesse nesse espaço. 

Ex: Vou em "Criar Anuncio", Escolho "Box Lateral 01" e anexo uma imagem de acordo com o tamanha do box e digito o link... e pronto aparece lá...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está procurando [Campos Personalizados](http://codex.wordpress.org/pt-br:Campos_Personalizados) (*custom fields*) e [Meta Boxes](http://codex.wordpress.org/pt-br:add_meta_box).

[image: custom fields e meta boxes]

Quando a gente cria um meta box, usa os custom fields para armazenar a informação. Se nosso field começa com `_` não vai aparecer no box de campos personalizados. A Imagem Destacada, por exemplo, é armazenada como `_thumbnail_id`.

Você pode simplesmente usar o box padrão *Campos personalizados* e ir acrescentado as URLs das imagens. Depois no *frontend* puxa os valores com [`get_post_meta( $postID, 'minhas_imagens );`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta).

Ou faz um meta box personalizado ([*Adding custom image fields and other fields at the same time*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14452453/1287812)) usando os *hooks* `add_meta_box` e `save_post`, que é o que [o plugin Orbit Slider faz](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wp-orbit-slider/trunk/index.php#L254). Ou então usa um plugin como [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) para gerenciar isso sem ter que programar nada.

Comment: Ajudou de mais man! obrigado!